# How to prevent HttpClient.SendAsync Method from sending duplicate data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there away to prevent `HttpClient.SendAsync` method from sending duplicate data. 
 For context purpose am getting data from one API and posting to another API

I have tried BackgroundWorker to check if async is busy before sending another record without success

```
                BackgroundWorker bw;
                bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                if (bw.IsBusy != true)
                {
                    bw.DoWork += (obj, ea) => TaskAsync() //containing httpclient.SendAsync;
                    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    bw.CancelAsync();
                }
```

Another solution I tried was `TaskAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Retrieved saved duplicate

This saved record in MSSQL

```
GL-CLH-8686 | 2022-04-27 21:44:47.907 
GL-CLH-8686 | 2022-04-27 21:44:51.237
```

Comment: You mean not sending 2 or more records at the same time? Or that the same record should not be sent twice?

Comment: same record shoudn't be sent twice.

Comment: Then you need to store that record somewhere (or a hash of it) and compare the incoming record to that set.

Comment: Used Redis hash to store values after a successful POST but then I would have duplicated records of successful POST.

Comment: In the case they happen at the same time or?

Comment: I have added a sample saved record in the question

Comment: But do you look up the record to see if it is a duplicate before you send it?

Comment: I do, the shown above record was new it was sent twice, after logging I realized the sendasync can send more one record at the same time

Comment: So you send from multiple threads?

Comment: No, one thread.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like we need to consider idempotency.

[Preventing Duplicate Web Requests To ASP.NET Core](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/preventing-duplicate-web-requests-to-aspnet-core)

This article uses the uniqueness of database existence values to limit repeated requests.

The easiest way I can cite is to encode the data in the request with the same content in a certain way, assuming that the encoding is named content, then record the current userid, and cache it in redis cache or other caches (databases can also) , for your business, after executing this method, you can release resources or delete this record. Of course, all the information can be completely recorded in the database, but a query operation will be added.